# PWM gate signals for three phase inverter in Pspice

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, inverter, gate-driving, pspice

[image: Simulation circuit]

I am comparing triangular (carrier) wave and sine waves(0-phase U, 120- Phase V,-120- Phase W) to generate varying duty PWM signals.

Gate drive signals for the high and low sides are proper if all op-amps inputs are from '0' ground.

For high side drive, I need to create isolated drive signals to separate HS1,HS2 and HS3 from each other. So, I have changed the ground of U6,U7 and U8 Opamp to '2', '1', and '3'. Changing ground has made the simulation not work. It seems that the ideal opamp works only with ground '0'.
I connected the opamp inputs to ground '0' through a giga ohm resistor. This made to simulation work again. but the waveforms are not proper. Instead of square pulses, I am getting half-sine pulses.

Is there any way to change the ground of the opamp?

or

Is there any other way to get isolated PWM signals for inverter?

Comment: Show the circuit diagram of your 3 phase inverter bridges.

Comment: If you just want it for simulation purposes, use a VCVS with a gain of 1 on the output of your op-amp, with the input tied to ground and the controlled source from gate to source of the high side FET.